# How do I set the value in a command shell for dotnet core

Tags: .net, shell, visual-studio-2015, asp.net-core

Running dotnet core command **dotnet run** in a command line I found this

*You can opt out of telemetry by setting a DOTNET_CLI_TELEMETRY_OPTOUT environment variable to 1 using your favorite shell.*

[image: DOTNET_CLI_TELEMETRY_OPTOUT]

How do I set this variable?

Thanks for your time.

Answer (score 78):

On Windows use

```
set DOTNET_CLI_TELEMETRY_OPTOUT=1
```

to avoid that telemetry data is sent by dotnet.exe in the current command line session.

**Or use**

```
setx DOTNET_CLI_TELEMETRY_OPTOUT 1
```

do disable this feature **permanently**.

Comment: Is there a way to `get` the value after using `setx` to confirm it was stored?

Comment: You can check the values using "set" (without quotes). Just enter set without trying to define an environment variable and you'll get the list of environment variables currently defined (including those defined using setx).

Comment: Note to PowerShell users: Since `setx.exe` is an external executable, `setx DOTNET_CLI_TELEMETRY_OPTOUT 1` works in PowerShell too (but, as in `cmd.exe`, is only seen in _future_ sessions, unless you also set it for the current one, with `$env:DOTNET_CLI_TELEMETRY_OPTOUT =  1`, PowerShell's equivalent to `cmd.exe`'s `set DOTNET_CLI_TELEMETRY_OPTOUT=1`).

Answer (score 13):

To set environment variable only for current cmd session write `set DOTNET_CLI_TELEMETRY_OPTOUT=1` or `set DOTNET_CLI_TELEMETRY_OPTOUT=true` (according to [.NET Core Tools Telemetry](https://learn.microsoft.com/pl-pl/dotnet/articles/core/tools/telemetry))

To set environment variable permanently use `setx` instead of `set`.

Edit:
For `setx` it has to be `setx DOTNET_CLI_TELEMETRY_OPTOUT 1`, and changes will only take effect when a new command window is opened - they do not affect the current CMD.

Developer Command Prompt is started with this `.bat` file: `C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 14.0\Common7\Tools\VsDevCmd.bat` so you can edit it and add permanent changes.

Comment: set DOTNET_CLI_TELEMETRY_OPTOUT=1 -> WORKS

However

setx DOTNET_CLI_TELEMETRY_OPTOUT=1 -> DOES NOT

Comment: @HamzaAhmedZia lose the "=" for setx

Answer (score 10):

In MacOS, use

```
echo "DOTNET_CLI_TELEMETRY_OPTOUT=1" | sudo tee -a /etc/environment
```

to add the variable setting to your environment.

http://gigi.nullneuron.net/gigilabs/net-core-tools-telemetry/

Comment: On macOS, as far as I know, `/etc/environment` neither exists by default nor is creating it on demand recognized by the OS. As of macOS 13 (Ventura), I'm not aware of any mechanism to define environment variables _system-wide_. By contrast, an `/etc/environment` file does seem to be honored on _Linux_ distros.

Answer (score 9):

For Bash on Unix-like operating systems (you can find out if you're using Bash by typing `echo $SHELL` in your terminal), you can do the following. Be aware that this only works pre-installation! To opt out after you've already installed the SDK, you have to set the environment variable, and then re-run the installer with this value set:

### For temporary opt-out for your user (reverts when you close your terminal session):

Set the variable

```
DOTNET_CLI_TELEMETRY_OPTOUT=1
```

Test if variable was set correctly (should see a `1` output)

```
echo $DOTNET_CLI_TELEMETRY_OPTOUT
```

### For permanent opt-out for your user

Open `.bashrc` in your text editor of choice (for Fedora the default is GNU Nano)

```
nano $HOME/.bashrc
```

Scroll to bottom of file. Add the following line

```
export DOTNET_CLI_TELEMETRY_OPTOUT=1
```

Save and exit (in GNU Nano, you can hit ctrl+x, and it will ask you to save). Then restart your terminal session.

```
 exec bash
```

Test if variable was set correctly (should see a `1` output):

```
echo $DOTNET_CLI_TELEMETRY_OPTOUT
```

Answer (score 0):

For fish shell user,

```
set -Ux DOTNET_CLI_TELEMETRY_OPTOUT 1
```