# How to query if DOTNET_CLI_TELEMETRY_OPTOUT is set permanently to TRUE?

Tags: .net, windows, powershell, settings

If i enter:

```
set DOTNET_CLI_TELEMETRY_OPTOUT=1
```

or

```
setx DOTNET_CLI_TELEMETRY_OPTOUT 1
```

to save this setting permanently, then the setting DOTNET_CLI_TELEMETRY_OPTOUT should be set to True, but how do i query it?

There is no

```
get DOTNET_CLI_TELEMETRY_OUTPUT
```

command.
And

```
echo $DOTNET_CLI_TELEMETRY_OPTOUT
```

does only give a 1, if

```
set DOTNET_CLI_TELEMETRY_OPTOUT 1
```

was entered instead of

```
set DOTNET_CLI_TELEMETRY_OPTOUT=1
```

that should be used.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**tl;dr**

- Use `$env:DOTNET_CLI_TELEMETRY_OPTOUT` to *get* the current process' value of environment variable `DOTNET_CLI_TELEMETRY_OPTOUT` (you can't tell from this value whether it reflects a *persistently* defined environment variable or one that was set for the *current process* only).
- Use, e.g. `$env:DOTNET_CLI_TELEMETRY_OPTOUT = 1` to *set* its value, but it will be in effect *for the current process only*.
- To *persistently* set a value (which is only supported on Windows), use `setx.exe` (as you tried) or use .NET APIs (see below).

  - Such persistent updates are only visible to *future* sessions (as process-level environment variables).
  - However, you can query the currently persisted value via .NET APIs (see below).

---

As for **what you tried**:

> `set DOTNET_CLI_TELEMETRY_OPTOUT=1`

You're trying to use `cmd.exe` syntax in PowerShell, which won't work.
In PowerShell, the above translates to the following, given that `set` is a built-in alias of the [`Set-Variable`](https://learn.microsoft.com/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.utility/set-variable), whose first positional parameter is `-Name`

```bash
Set-Variable -Name DOTNET_CLI_TELEMETRY_OPTOUT=1
```

This creates a *shell-only* variable *literally* named `DOTNET_CLI_TELEMETRY_OPTOUT=1` *without a value* (`$null`).

By *shell-only* variable I mean a [regular PowerShell variable](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_Variables) that is known to the current PowerShell session only, and - unlike *environment* variables - is *not* seen by other processes.

---

To **define an [*environment* variable](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_Environment_Variables) *for the current process***, use the **`$env:` namespace**:

```bash
$env:DOTNET_CLI_TELEMETRY_OPTOUT = 1
```

You can query the value with the same syntax, which works equally for *persistent* environment variables and those defined only for the current process:

```bash
$env:DOTNET_CLI_TELEMETRY_OPTOUT
```

---

**PowerShell** offers ***no* direct support for defining *persistent* environment variables**.

Using the **`setx.exe` utility** (on Windows) - as you tried - *is* an option.

You **can also use [.NET APIs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-US/dotnet/api/System.Environment.SetEnvironmentVariable)**:

```bash
# 'User' creates / updates a persistent definition for the *current user*.
# Use 'Machine' to create / update a machine-level definition, but 
# note that doing so requires *elevation* (running as admin).
[Environment]::SetEnvironmentVariable('DOTNET_CLI_TELEMETRY_OPTOUT', '1', 'User')
```

Note, however, that in both cases the new / updated value will only be seen in *future* sessions, i.e. will only automatically surface as *process-level* environment variables there.

You can, however, use .NET APIs again to retrieve the currently persisted value directly from the registry, assuming you know its scope (`User` vs. `Machine` - you may have to try both); e.g.:

```bash
[Environment]::GetEnvironmentVariable('DOTNET_CLI_TELEMETRY_OPTOUT', 'User')
```

**Note**:

- Neither of the two persistent-update methods are suitable for updating `REG_EXPAND_SZ`-based persistent environment-variable definitions, i.e. those expressed in terms of *other* environment variables.
- Notably, this means that the `PATH` environment variable shouldn't be updated this way - see [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/q/714877/45375) for a solution.

Comment: Thank you very much, that solved it. Yesterday before I asked her my question i used this [link]https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39306618/how-do-i-set-the-value-in-a-command-shell-for-dotnet-core[/link] answer, but it was insufficient.

Comment: Glad to hear it, @Coder; my pleasure. Yes, the linked answer is focused on `cmd.exe` and other shells, not PowerShell.